# Recursive check if digit is ascending java

Tags: java, recursion

I have this code and it properly executes, however, it doesn't check for negatives and if a number is 223344 then it's ascending but it returns false when it should return true.

```
    int newp = x / 10;

    if (newp == 0) {
        return true;
    } else
    if (x % 10 <= newp % 10) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return digitsSorted(newp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `<=` means?

Comment: ...and for negative numbers, why not put `x = Math.abs(x)` as the first statement (or an if statement).

Comment: I know what <= means but i h have never used .abs

Comment: okay .abs worked but i still cant figure out the case of 223344

Comment: never mind i got it